# Should I ask for the state in a registration form for new clients who live in the USA?

Tags: database, web-applications, data

Basically, on almost every international site, they ask for the united state you live in, once you selected that you live in the USA. Right now I'm programming a registration form for an Austria company that wants to operate world wide in the future.

People who register can even live in the USA. **So is it recommend to ask for the state?**

Asking for a state would require a new field in UI and DB that is filled only on Americans. I'd like to avoid it, since the [state can be determined by the ZIP code](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/24/ZIP_Code_zones.svg) that has to be entered, too. Otherwise the correct perform would be to set up an SQL trigger to make sure that field cannot be set on non Americans, but for what reason I need it at all? Did I miss anything?

Comment: Do other countries have provinces and postal codes? Hint: yes. Just because we have our names for those entities in the U.S. does not make us special.

Comment: You see this type of thing because sometimes program behavior actually *depends* on the state or province of the user, more often than not for legal reasons.  Asking now would ensure that should it ever come up (cross your fingers), you'll already have the data saved.  Otherwise, if you don't need this information now, you don't need to save it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that having this sort of sub-federal jurisdiction above the level of a municipality happens in many countries, not just in the US (e.g Australia, Canada, China, India, Mexico...)

To answer your question, you (modiX) need to understand why one would ask for the state (or province or territory). There are two primary reasons:

1. If you need to use old-fashioned postal mail to send information to a registrant - the state/province/territory is an important part of the mailing address
2. If you have a presence in a state (etc) which requires charging tax to registrants who live in the same state, but does not require it of people who live outside of it.

Don't just do it because you see others do it - that's just cargo cult UI design.

Comment: The US tax rule is not "if you are based in" but rather usually "If you have a physical presence in".

Answer (score 4):

There are fringe cases where zip codes can actually cross state lines. Amazingly stupid, but true:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_code#By_geography

Following trends blindly might be bad UI design but bucking them without a healthy dose of paranoia is a bad idea too.

Answer (score 0):

> Asking for a state would require a new field in UI and DB that is filled only on Americans. I'd like to avoid it, since the state can be determined by the ZIP code that has to be entered, too.

You're basically relying on another database if you're trying to get a state from a zip code. That would add a bit more latency to your web application because your script that processes the zip code in the registration form will have to make a call to a special server that retrieves the correct state from the database.

I'm sorry if you won't agree with this, but I recommend not avoiding that extra field. Instead, you should add it as a 2-character field to represent the short form of the state because there is a chance that the correct state could not be found based on a given zip code. Also with this method, the latency is substantially lower since you won't have to lookup the state on the special server every time you want the state since its right there in the database.

Personally, I'd rather waste two bytes per applicant to hold the american state information rather than waste several hundred extra milliseconds to lookup the state based on the zip code every time the state is required.

> Otherwise the correct procedure could be to set up an SQL trigger to make sure that field cannot be set on non Americans

No need. If you add the field for the state, and the applicant is a non-american, then use a value in the field that doesn't represent a real state. For example, "XX". Then you can use simple SQL SELECT statements to find applicants based on states, and for non-americans, if you follow my example, and you want non-americans, your SQL statement would be something similar to:

```
SELECT customer,address,state,zip FROM customers WHERE state = "XX";
```

But then again, it depends on your fields. In my example, I assumed your table is named "customers" and the fields are customer, address, state, and zip.